# How to Pause and Resume Hot reload through Dotnet CLI

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, dotnet-cli, hot-reload

I am working with .Net 6 API project and i am using the **dotnet watch run** command for Hot reload.

Whenever there is any file change browser is getting refreshed, but i want to decide when the browser should get refreshed. My requirement is to refresh it after making few changes.

I have seen this feature in Visual studio 2022 as there in the below image. Looking for same in Dotnet CLI.

[image: VS2022 Hot reload]

Comment: There's no such net cli command for hot reload to work after several files stored. learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet